# How to close the drawer if i have opened the drawer on the drawer?

Tags: arrays, react-native

I've created the drawer under that the menu is opening another drawer but if the first drawer is opened and I click out of focus that is closed but if two drawers are open than if I click out of focus it's not closing

I'm using native base drawer for this and want to add items in the menu dynamically from the server

drawers are opening normally but if i open two drawer one in another they are not closing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can close and open the drawer programmatically using the below functions

```
openDrawer();
closeDrawer();
```

Get access to your drawer using refs and call these functions eg.

```
this.refs['yourDrawer'].openDrawer();
this.refs['yourDrawer'].closeDrawer();
```

Comment: but i'm not able to access the reference i'm facing error on the next page that reference is undefined

Comment: my bad i was calling the wrong method for closing drawer that's why i was not able to close drawer